# change css while vue is calculating

Tags: vue.js

On user-click some potentially heavy calculations ('set-selection' below) get made, so I want to show the user that the app is busy, while it is calculating. I've tried the following:

```
data() {
    return {
      isWaiting: false,
    };
},

methods: {
handleClick(node) {
  this.cursorWait();
  this.$nextTick()
      .then(this.$emit("set-selectie", node))
      .then(this.cursorClear);
},
cursorWait() {
  this.isWaiting = true;
},
cursorClear() {
  this.isWaiting = false;
}
```

The `$emit` takes some time, so I want vue to show a simple css change (cursor) based on the `this.isWaiting` data. However, it looks like what vue is actually doing is not responding to the change in `this.isWaiting` until the calculation is done.

As you can see I've tried `$nextTick`, but I have also tried lifecycle methods and `this.$forceUpdate()`. They don't work either.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: beforeUpdate lifecycle method in vue  might help !

Comment: You must remember JavaScript is single-threaded, and that includes UI as well. (Excluding webworkers, but they can't touch UI anyway.) So nothing can happen while something else is happening.

Comment: you are assuming that `$emit` will return a promise, but it doesn't!

Comment: I have the feeling that I need more code to say something useful about this. Where is the calculation method triggered?

Comment: `.then(this.$emit("set-selectie", node))` this should be `.then(() => this.$emit("set-selectie", node))`

Comment: and this `.then(this.cursorClear);` should be `.then(this.cursorClear.bind(this));` or `.then(() => this.cursorClear());`

Comment: Also, you are assuming that `this.$emit("set-selectie", node)` is asynchronous but it is not, so this won't work.

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag does your last comment negate the others? Anyhow, the question is: how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like browsers are very inconsistent in how they handle cursor changes through CSS.

We did get the following working (within the handleClick method above):

```
    let _this = this;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      document.getElementById("treemain").style.background = "#ccc";
      document.getElementById("treemain").style.color = "#666";
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        _this.$emit("set-selectie", node);
        document.getElementById("treemain").style.background = "#fff";
        document.getElementById("treemain").style.color = "#011d47;";
      });
    });
```

So we're basically getting outside of Vue to solve this with basic javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this an issue, "On user-click some potentially heavy calculations get made, so I want to show the user that the app is busy, while it is calculating."

I want to put what I have tried to fixed such situation :

Let the calculation is `asynchronous` and you never know when it get finished or a `function` which take some time to get executed.

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data : {
    text: "",
    inProgress : false
  },
  methods : {
   calculate : function(){
     this.inProgress = true;
       new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
         setTimeout(function(){
         resolve('I am done')
        },3000)
      }).then(e=>{
          this.text = e;
           this.inProgress = false;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="calculate()"> click me</button>
  <p>{{text}}</p>
  <div v-show="inProgress">
    loading...
  </div>
</div>
```

I have just tried a way to do that as I was not able to reproduce same situation due to lack of code information.

I hope this might help to get you through.

Comment: Thanks. That's the one thing I had thought of but hadn't tried yet, but it too doesn't work. 
Vue continues to only redraw the dom after the calculation is done, not before.